# Plot multiple-regression line in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

Somewhat newbie question here. I'd like to use ggplot2 to plot my multiple regression model, but I ran into an error. I did some research on the forum before deciding to ask the community. The [original question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261776/r-plot-multiple-regression-line-with-confidence-intervals-with-ggplot2) was posted in the wrong forum by mistake.

I understand how to plot a simple linear regression:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=X, y=Y))+geom_point()+ 
  geom_smooth(method='lm',formula=Y~X)
```

But when I tried to do it for multiple regression:

```
Model<-lm(Y~x1*x2*x3*x4*x5, data, na.action=na.omit)

ggplot(data, aes(x=X, y=Model))+geom_point()+ 
  geom_smooth(method='lm',formula=Y~x1*x2*x3*x4*x5)
```

I get this error:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type lm. Defaulting to continuous.
>       Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (209): x, y

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using abline() function?

try using

```
abline(Model,lwd=3,col="red")
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly, either placing it between backquotes or indenting it. The content of your answer is good, I’m commenting on the look.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this for multiple regression if you have two independent variables,

```
set.seed(1) 
data <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(100, 5, 2), x2=rnorm(100, 10, 5)) # some random data
data$y <- 3*data$x1 + 2*data$x2 + rnorm(100, 2, 5)

lmFit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data)

x1 <- seq(from = min(data$x1), to =  max(data$x1), by = 0.1)
x2 <- seq(from = min(data$x2), to = max(data$x2), by = 0.1)
y <- outer(X = x1, Y = x2, FUN = function(x1, x2) {
  predict(lmFit, newdata = data.frame(x1 = x1, x2 = x2))
})

open3d()
bg3d("white")
material3d(col="black")
persp3d(x1, x2, y,  col = "green3", xlab = "x1", ylab = "x2", zlab = "y",theta=50, phi=25, expand=0.75, ticktype="detailed")
points3d(data$x1, data$x2, data$y, col = "red", size=5)
```

[image]